# Auto deploy Google Cloud Functions from Google Cloud Source Control

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-source-repos

I can't figure out how to automatically deploy newly pushed commits of Cloud Functions either from Cloud Source Control or from GitHub directly. I have found a similar solution by creating another function and GitHub webhook, but since Functions can't SSH (and have SSH keys installed), it is only working with Public Repos. (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-github-auto-deployer)

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could use Google Cloud Builder to achieve this goal. Create a trigger on your repository, and the triggered build deploys the new code to Google Cloud Function.

I made a quick example: https://github.com/Philmod/auto-deploy-gcf

Cheers,
Philmod

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find a reasonable workaround for this issue. I hope that it helps others struggling with this same issue.

### Required setup

Before you get started with these steps, you'll need to setup SSH keys on your CI/CD system. This is what grants your build system ssh access to your private repo. Here are a couple of articles which discuss how to do that.

- [Gitlab CI 101 - SSH keys](https://moduslaborandi.net/post/gitlabci-101-ssh-keys/)
- [An Alternative to npm Private Modules](http://fiznool.com/blog/2015/05/20/an-alternative-to-npm-private-modules/)

You'll also need to install the package via `git+ssh` so that it's included in your `package.json` (and optionally `yarn.lock`).

```
yarn add git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:erichiggins/top_secret.git
```

At this point, you should see the following entry in your `package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "top_secret": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:erichiggins/top_secret.git"
},
...
```

### Installing the package (twice)

Here are the commands I run inside a shell script on my CI/CD setup, just before the deploy stage, in order to install private repos as packages using `git+ssh`. I'll use a fake package name of `top_secret` for my example to make it more clear.

(*I'm using `yarn` and GitLab in this example, but the same applies to `npm` and GitHub if you prefer.*)

```
yarn install
cd node_modules/top_secret
yarn pack
mv top_secret-v*.tgz ../../
cd ../../
yarn add file:top_secret-v1.0.0.tgz
```

**Note:** The `yarn pack` command will produce a filename that includes a version number, but you can't `yarn add` with a wildcard (`*`). I've run into issues using `yarn pack --filename` with a generic, version-less filename, so you may need to either hardcode this or find a creative solution that uses the filename generated by `yarn pack`.

### Results

If you try running these two commands locally, you'll notice that you end up with just one new entry for `top_secret` inside the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file, which will look like this:

```
"top_secret": "file:node_modules/top_secret",
```

Here's what's happening:

1. You're installing the private repo as a package via `git+ssh` on a system that has access.
2. You're repackaging it from your `node_modules/` directory into a tarball file (.tgz).
3. You're installing the same package from a local tarball file using `file:`
4. Because the package name is identical, it replaces the `git+ssh` entry in `package.json` with the `file:` entry.

Your deployment to Cloud Functions should now proceed without any issues, and with your private package included.  Good luck and let me know if you have any problems with these instructions -- I'd be happy to correct any mistakes and rewrite anything that is unclear.

### Alternative approach

If you don't mind the extra effort or the private repo does not change frequently enough to justify the additional complexity in your CI/CD, you can also use `npm pack`/`yarn pack` to create a tarball file, run the same `yarn add file:...` command listed above to modify your `package.json` and simply check the tarball file into your repo.

**Note:** Be mindful that if the repo you're checking the tarball file into is public, the source of your private repo/package will also be made public.

### References:

- [Documentation for `yarn add`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/)
- [Documentation for `yarn pack`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/pack/)
- [Documentation for `npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack)
- [Documentation for `npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)
- [Gitlab CI 101 - SSH keys](https://moduslaborandi.net/post/gitlabci-101-ssh-keys/)
- [An Alternative to npm Private Modules](http://fiznool.com/blog/2015/05/20/an-alternative-to-npm-private-modules/)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work - the deploy fails every time because it's not uploading the node_modules folder and therefore it can't find my private module. What are you using to deploy the function?

Comment: @Tom This code snippet may need an adjustment -- I seem to recall it working for me, then having an issue later. I'll go through it today and fix it, then let you know what changes are needed. Hopefully we can get it working for you.

Comment: @Tom I've updated the instructions to reflect a solution that should work and added a simpler alternative solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: I use PACKED=`ls ${NAME}-*.tgz` from a generic script. However, if I start with an empty node_modules directory, `npm install ./${PACKED} --ignore-scripts --offline` downloads half the internet when all I want to do is edit package.json

Comment: sed -E -i -e "s/\"${NAME}\": ?\"[^\"]*\"(,?)$/\"${NAME}\": \"file:${PACKED}\"\1/" package.json

Comment: @Philmod answer below is more elegant, given the platform in question is Cloud Functions.